# How to select a whole of clob column oracle?

Tags: oracle, dbvisualizer

I want to select a whole clob data without spisify to lenght of the return.

this my request but with a limit lenght.

```
select 
contentType,name, 
DBMS_LOB.substr(DATAS, dbms_lob.getlength(DATAS)) as doc 
from 
AutorisationDoc 
where AUTORIS_DOC = '62119367419202074';
```

this the result that the natural select `select  DATAS from AutorisationDoc` return

[image]

Comment: why are you using SBSTR(), just add the LOB column to your query as is

Comment: dos not work I want to select the clob as a String

Comment: "does not work"... what does it mean? You're getting an error?

Comment: that's return a clob data with its lenght not a string

Comment: how are you executing this query, exactly? in sqldev, if you run select (clob) from table and execute with F9, we show you the text

Comment: In db visualizer I run this query but the result not like My needs and I use to same result to decode it webmethods

Comment: then tag tb viz or maybe go ask in their forums - def add a screenshot to your question showing what you see. And then tell us exactly what your web architecture will be

Comment: look at the edit question

Comment: your query is fine, the problem is with your tool

Answer (score 0):

From the [DB Visualiser 10.0 User Guide](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Editing+Table+Data#EditingTableData-EditingBinary/BLOBandCLOBData)

> ## Editing Binary/BLOB and CLOB Data
>
> Due to the nature of binary/BLOB and CLOB data, cells of these types
>   can only be fully modified and viewed in the Cell Editor. (There is
>   partial support in the Form Editor to view image data and to load from
>   file).
>
> In the grid, Binary/BLOB and CLOB data is by default presented by an
>   icon and the size of the value. You can select another presentation
>   format in the Tools Properties dialog, in the Grid / Binary/BLOB and
>   CLOB Data category under the General tab. Selecting By Value results
>   in performance penalties and the memory consumption increases
>   dramatically.
>
> In the same Tool Properties category, you can also specify how to
>   handle Copy/Paste and Drag and Drop when pasting binary data in a
>   target component that doesn't support binary data.
>
> Editing binary data can be done by importing from a file or via the
>   text editor in the Cell Editor. You can also copy the file in the
>   operating system's file browser and paste it into a BLOB/CLOB cell.
>
> Binary data in DbVisualizer is the generic term for several common
>   binary database types:
>
> - LONGVARBINARY
> - BINARY
> - VARBINARY
> - BLOB
>
> The Image Viewer supports displaying full size images for the
>   following formats:
>
> - GIF
> - JPG
> - PNG
> - TIFF
> - BMP
> - PDF

So, you can use your query:

```
select contentType,
       name, 
       DATAS
from   AutorisationDoc 
where  AUTORIS_DOC = '62119367419202074';
```

But you need to view `DATAS` in the Cell Editor to see the full content (not the grid, which just shows "an icon and the size of the value").

This can be found:

> ## Using the Cell Editor/Viewer
>
> The Cell Viewer is available in the right-click menu for all grids in DbVisualizer.